# Access Sybase database from PHP

Tags: php, database, sybase

I have an application based on Sybase database. The application is running on a Windows Server 2003. I tried to fetch the database from the `php` and it is showing a number of `dll` files are missing including the php sybase extension. I checked the php extension dir and found that the file exists on the path where it is showing the errors.

Here i would like to mention that i installed xampp 1.8.0 on the windows server and enabled the sybase extension form the php.ini.

I used the following code to connect as mentioned on the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-connect.php)

```
<?php
$link = sybase_connect('SYBASE', '', '')
        or die("Could not connect !");
echo "Connected successfully";
sybase_close($link);
?>
```

**== Update ==**

It was showing that the following `dll` files were missing and i downloaded and added them manually.

`libcs.dll`

`libintl.dll`

`iconv.dll`

Now i am getting the following error,

`The procedure entry point iconv_open could not be located in the dynamic link library iconv.dll`

This error is present from the beginning of enabling the Sybase PHP extension.

`PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sybase_ct.dll' - the specified procedure could not be found`

Comment: It would likely help if you provided the full dll names as well as the complete error message(s) you're receiving.

Comment: @markp thanks for responding. I updated the question and mentioned the dll names. the missing dll were coming one after another. Like when i add the first dll then it shows that another one is missing

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen `unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sybase_ct.dll'` the issue has come down to a) having an old/outdated set of libs or b) using an application that references the 'old' Sybase lib names (with ASE 15, Sybase changed the names of their libs and some apps haven't picked up on this).

For the first issue the obvious (?) resolution would be to download the appropriate set of Sybase libs (which is going to depend on your application code/version as well as the ASE version). [Not enough info in your post to know if this explains your scenario.]

For the second issue there's a relatively easy solution (the following is based on a PHP app that has a Sybase-specific sub-directory containing the Sybase client-side libs):

- in a Windows cmd window ..
- source the *.bat file for your application [load your app's env]
- cd to the Sybase sub-directory named `...\OCS*\scripts`
- run `copylibs.bat`
- try starting your PHP app again and ...
- if the issue is fixed then the `php_sybase_ct.dll` error message should go away